# New array for music symbols

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have background musics from the library, any ideas how to solve this code by clicking the button to change it?

```
var BeachBall: CrashBash_BeachBall = new CrashBash_BeachBall();
var BrickDive: LEGOIsland2_BrickDive = new LEGOIsland2_BrickDive();
var BloocheepOcean: MarioHoops_BloocheepOcean = new MarioHoops_BloocheepOcean();
var Underwater: MarioTeachesTyping2_Underwater = new MarioTeachesTyping2_Underwater();
var UnderPressure: CrashBandicootNST_UnderPressure = new CrashBandicootNST_UnderPressure();
var CalmWaters: DireDireDocks_CalmWaters = new DireDireDocks_CalmWaters();
var Level1: TreasureCove_Level1 = new TreasureCove_Level1();
var Level2: TreasureCove_Level2 = new TreasureCove_Level2();
var Level3: TreasureCove_Level3 = new TreasureCove_Level3();
        
var music: Array = new Array(CalmWaters, BloocheepOcean, UnderPressure, Underwater, BeachBall, BrickDive, Level1, Level2, Level3); 
             
// Changing the Background Music
music_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, on_pressMusic);
music[Math.floor(Math.random()*music.length)].play();

if(!sound)
{
    sound_channel = CalmWaters.play(0, int.MAX_VALUE);
    sound_channel.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.4); 
}

function on_pressMusic(event: MouseEvent): void 
{
    /*
    var random: int = int(Math.random() * sounds[0].length);
    play_music(sounds[0][random]);
    var sMusic:Button = new Button();
    sMusic.play();
    */
    
    if (is_Playing == true) //# if music is already playing 
    {
        music_player.stop();
    }
    
    musicNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (musicList.length-1));
    music_object = new (musicList[musicNum]); 
    
    audioTime = 0; //# seconds to start from within track
    music_player = music_object.play(audioTime);
    is_Playing = true;
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
        at BlowfishPong_fla::MainTimeline/on_pressMusic()[BlowfishPong_fla.MainTimeline::frame27:205]
```

All of the codes are updated. any ideas how to solve and fix this for their future coding.

Comment: **top code** : Why the `} ` at the bottom? Are you closing something that started as `{ ` and so you need this other bottom `} ` also? If Yes... that means your vars are trapped inside your `{ vars code here... }` so the other functions like  `on_pressMusic` cannot access them. Solution make them global ( meaning not inside a `{ }` block of code).

Comment: **middle code** : Show the function that holds this code... Does the error happen at this line: `sound_channel = CalmWaters.play(0, int.MAX_VALUE);`? If Yes, then using **global vars** as said from above comment should fix it.

Comment: **(1)** Look at my edit... Is that how your code is written in your editor? The error says it's from **line 205** but I don't know which one is line 205... All you keep saying is _"how to fix this... fix this... fix this..."_ but why not show what is line 205's code so we know what your "this" means? I think this line 205 is inside the `on_pressMusic` function... **(2)** Also [back in April](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71858740/new-array-for-music-symbols#comment127087262_71862207) I told you about `new` constructors, did you try the ideas there to fix this constructor error?

Comment: OK but please can you answer my **two** questions. **(1)** Is your code structured like my edit, if not then... **show your code** for doing same things (like show your vars, event listeners and functions), show code that could be fully testable by others to get same error as your compiler. **(2)** Did you try anything from [my advice in back in April](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71858740/new-array-for-music-symbols#comment127087262_71862207) and **if yes** then show that testable code and the error it gave.

Comment: No. But, there is a TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert MarioTeachesTyping2_Underwater@2ca79a40031 to flash.net.URLRequest.
 at BlowfishPong_Ver1__fla::MainTimeline/on_pressMusic()[BlowfishPong_Ver1__fla.MainTimeline::frame28:209]

Comment: Update your post to show the code you are using to get the error (maybe someone can test it for you)... Also show what is code on line 209 (of frame 28)

Comment: **PS:** This is why I almost give up on helping you... I asked _"Is that how your code is written in your editor"_ and you said _"No... it's still the same."_ Wow!! You don't understand that I don't care if it's still same!! How can your brain not understand the situation is: _"Oh I see.. this person is asking **how my code is** because they can't see it. Hey, **I will show them** the correct structure so they understand how to fix my error"_  but here, you just tell me _"No... it's still the same."_... I want you to win, but if you do not help others to help you then it will be slow progress.

Comment: **PS:** _"there is a TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed"_ please **show your code** because the code that you put in the Question does not do any URL requesting. There is no reason for getting a `request` error when you say that you add a sound object from library. Either you have code doing something but did not show it here or maybe just try  download a new version of Adobe Animate (your version has strange errors about things your code is not doing)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var BeachBall: CrashBash_BeachBall = new CrashBash_BeachBall();
var BrickDive: LEGOIsland2_BrickDive = new LEGOIsland2_BrickDive();
var BloocheepOcean: MarioHoops_BloocheepOcean = new MarioHoops_BloocheepOcean();
var CalmWaters: DireDireDocks_CalmWaters = new DireDireDocks_CalmWaters();
var Level1: TreasureCove_Level1 = new TreasureCove_Level1();
var Level2: TreasureCove_Level2 = new TreasureCove_Level2();
var Level3: TreasureCove_Level3 = new TreasureCove_Level3();
var Underwater: MarioTeachesTyping2_Underwater = new MarioTeachesTyping2_Underwater();
var UnderPressure: CrashBandicootNST_UnderPressure = new CrashBandicootNST_UnderPressure();

var myNum :uint = 0;
var audioTime :uint = 0;
var music_object :Sound;
var music_player :SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var is_Playing :Boolean = false;

var music_list :Array = new Array();
music_list =    [   BeachBall, BrickDive, BloocheepOcean, CalmWaters, 
                    Level1, Level2, Level3, Underwater, UnderPressure 
                ]; 
             
//# Changing the Background Music
music_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, on_pressMusic);

function on_pressMusic (event:MouseEvent) : void  
{
    if ( is_Playing == true ) //# if music is already playing 
    { music_player.stop(); }
    
    myNum = Math.floor( Math.random() * (music_list.length-1) );
    music_object = new ( music_list[ myNum ] ); 
    
    audioTime = 0; //# seconds to start from within track
    music_player = music_object.play( audioTime );
    is_Playing = true;
  
}
```

Comment: OK. What about this code: if(!sound){ 
 sound = new Sound();
 sound.load(new URLRequest('E:/Flash Animations/Folder 1/2- Depths of Aquatron/Bit-Bot Math Voyage/Music/Dire Dire Docks Remix - Calm Waters.mp3'));
 sound_channel = sound.play(0, int.MAX_VALUE);
 SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.4); 
}

Comment: But I have an Error when I clicked the button: "#1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor."

Comment: There are two codes. Where is the error from, is it from **my** shown code or is it from **your** shown code? Anyways... a constructor uses `new` so replace any lines with **new** keyword... In my code this means: try `music_object = new...` becomes `music_object =  music_list[ myNum ];` if still not working then make it using constructor but load your audio from Array for example: `music_object = new Sound(); music_object.load( music_list[0] );`. Replace the `0` with `myNum` once you can get first track in music_list Array to work.

Comment: PS: If the error is in your code: ... I can only see two constructors `new Sound` and `new SoundTransform` so one of those two is giving you problems. Instead of `SoundMixer.soundTransform = ...` try instead as `sound_channel.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.4);`. PS: You should not create a `new Sound` every time the button is clicked. Outside of any functions, just create your Sound variables once, then inside functions you update the same Sound with a new audio path whenever button is clicked.

Comment: Then when I clicked the home button to return to the main page, the music is still playing...

Comment: I still have a same error, any ideas how to fix this. I have already updated the scripts above

Comment: I don't know. The compiler says the error is from line **205** in function `on_pressMusic1` but you did not show the function and say which one is line 205... Also your other code is showing that the click event is looking for function `on_pressMusic` ... is there two functions? Like `pressMusic` and `pressMusic1`? ... Finally why the top code got `}` at the end? Is it closing/ending a function? **A variable created inside a function only works for that same function** If you need different functions to access same var then declare the variable at top before any functions start.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71858740/edit) to show the full code from starting at top of page until up to (and include) the function `on_pressMusic1` ... Maybe it will be easier to understand what you did (you keep showing small pieces of code that are useless for understanding the reason for your error message)...

Comment: My question and an error are fully updated.